# Serialize Feign Json Response to object

Tags: json, response, feign

I've the following Json response coming from a Feign client:

```
{
  "maxResults": 1,
  "total": 5,
  "isLast": false,
  "values": [
    {
      "id": 37,
      "self": "https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/agile/1.0/sprint/23",
      "state": "active",
      "name": "sprint 1",
      "goal": "sprint 1 goal"
    }
  ]
}
```

The feign client:

```
@FeignClient(name = "jira")
public interface JiraFeignClient {

    @GetMapping("/rest/agile/1.0/board/{boardId}/sprint?state=active&maxResults=1")
    ActiveSprintResponse getActiveSprint(@PathVariable String boardId);
}
```

I'd like to define the `ActiveSprintResponse` class in order to have the information related to the "values" property (I'm only interested in those) of the json response but I don't understand how can I easily represent it.
I would have no problems for the properties "maxResults", "total" etc... but how can easily unpack "values"? I can assume I will always have only one element in the value array.

I've tried defining it like that but it clearly does not work:

```
public class ActiveSprintResponse {

    private final String id;
    private final String self;
    private final String name;
    private final String goal;

    public ActiveSprintResponse(String id, String self, String name, String goal) {
        this.id = id;
        this.self = self;
        this.name = name;
        this.goal = goal;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a class that represents the root JSON object. You can define a property for the `values` of type List then:

```
public class ActiveSprintResponseList {

  private List<ActiveSprintResponse> values;

  // (Other fields omitted for simplicity)
 
  public void setValues(List<ActiveSprintResponse> values) {
    this.values = values;
  }

  public List<ActiveSprintResponse> getValues() {
    return values;
  }
}
```

you then need to declare that class as return type:

```
@FeignClient(name = "jira")
public interface JiraFeignClient {

    @GetMapping("/rest/agile/1.0/board/{boardId}/sprint?state=active&maxResults=1")
    ActiveSprintResponseList getActiveSprint(@PathVariable String boardId);
}
```

and use it on the calling side:

```
ActiveSprintResponseList response = client.getActiveSprint(..);
List<ActiveSprintResponse> values = response.getValues();
// work with values
```